# How to upgrade project version of React native

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, upgrade, react-native-ios

I have an application which runs on react-native 0.59.5 I want to upgrade to the latest version which 0.64.0.

Best way to upgrade the project

Answer (score 1):

```
npx react-native upgrade
cd ios 
pod install
```

> for upgrade to specific version  You may specify a React Native
> version by passing an argument, e.g. to upgrade to 0.64.0

```
npx react-native upgrade 0.61.0-rc.0
```

**see the changes in the code with upgrade helper**
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/